# When to dereference a object in java web mvc

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on spring web mvc and recently encountered java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

So, i was reading about it and the major mistake i am doing is that i am not deferencing the used objects. so GC is not cleaning lot of memory.

Now the question is when to dereference it.

Here is basic out flow:

```
From front end user sends a request

server calls a library with the users request

library returns it a big chunk of array of results.

server forwards it to front end.
```

Now til this point i cannot dereference results array as i need the result object. Am i correct ?
So when user sends new request should i clean the results array and call the library with new request.

Also i used -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to get a dump file. But i dont see the dump file in project folder. In log i see that dump file is created. Did any one run into this case.

Comment: Where are you keeping the results array?  Are you putting it in the `Session`, or some comparable in-memory cache?  Because if not then it will automatically become a candidate for garbage collection as soon as the request completes.

Comment: Have you tried upping your heap size?

-Xmx3g should give a bunch of breathing room (3g = 3 gigs)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the solution for this type of problem is:

1. (Obvious) Increase the maximum heap settings using `-Xmx`, get a bigger hardware. This appraoch might not be scalable, but could provide short term solution to the problem
2. Ask yourself do you really need *a big chunk* ? If not try requesting smaller chunks instead to conserve heap usage. Make sure you are not holding reference to an object any longer than you should. As soon as you know your variable is no longer needed, set it to null so they can be garbage collected.

Comment: I used visual vm to see how much memory is being consumed. I see that memory usage is gradually increasing. I assume that i am not de referencing some objects. Am i right

Comment: Most likely yes. If you're code is healthy, memory graph should look like a sawtooth without significant increase over period of time. Check what classes instance are filling up your heap, and see if you can free up reference to those objects so GC can clean more

Comment: I see  these lines. but not able to find dump file:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid728.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [199269982 bytes in 4.174 secs]. Any idea where it will go. I am using eclipse.

Comment: ok. Found the location. it is going to eclipse folder. i will try analysing which objects are eating memory.

Answer (score 1):

It will be very difficult to help you without a http://sscce.org/ . The JVM does the GC for you and if your objects have well defined scope they should get GCed automatically.

I would recommend you start by increasing the heap memory figuring out these :

what is the scope of Result array (Global or restricted to method calls hierarchy i.e passed through method invocation stack to fron-end)?

In case it has global scope is it part of a singleton instance or created per request instance?. What objects are stored in the Result array are they referenced anywhere else in your code?.

You can Use Jhat to get the object reference graph and find out who else is referencing the objects (DISCLAIMER: It would get messy if the objects stored in the array contain references to other objects & which is usually the case)

[Better ways to identify objects not getting garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495849/better-ways-to-identify-objects-not-getting-garbage-collected)